# Getting original bios

Tags: bios

I am using HP Pavilion DM4 1101tx laptop with windows 7 preinstalled . Few months ago I upgraded from windows 7 to 10 and my recovery partition was deleted accidentally . So my original softwares including drivers and bios were lost .

So I want to know what bios was preinstalled on my laptop and where would I get it?
Is there any way ?

Comment: If you didn't changed BIOS, then it has probably still the original one. Also I don't think recovery partition would have contained BIOS, as it's not subject to regular changes  / updates, and also it's generally preserved during reinstalls.

Comment: Its not possible for the installation of an OS to wipe your bios firmware.  Your recovery partition isn't required, it doesn't do anything, that an installation disk of Windows cannot do.  Typically its not possible to go back to a previous version of a bios firmware, only upgrade the firmware, for a varity of technical reasons.

Comment: The BIOS is in a chip on the motherboard, not on the hard drive. Even physical removal of the hard drive would not effect the BIOS.

Comment: hanks for helping .

The problem is I have got fixed mode switchable graphics on my laptop ( intel HD graphics + ati mobility radeon hd 5470 ) . After the fresh installation of windows 7 I am unable to enable switchable graphics . When I install graphics driver provided by HP the backlight of the screen turns off after boot .

To resolve this I have to disable ati graphics from safe mode .

And I have seen somewhere that updating bios would fix it . Thats why I was asking for some old bios .

Answer (score 2):

Installing Windows 10 won't update your BIOS. That will only happen if you deliberately download and install the BIOS update that HP provides.

As to where to find them, [Two are listed on the HP site](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-dm4-Entertainment-Notebook-PC-series/4247657/model/4288424) for your model, if you select *Windows 7 (64 bit)*.

Comment: hanks for helping .

The problem is I have got fixed mode switchable graphics on my laptop ( intel HD graphics + ati mobility radeon hd 5470 ) . After the fresh installation of windows 7 I am unable to enable switchable graphics . When I install graphics driver provided by HP the backlight of the screen turns off after boot .

To resolve this I have to disable ati graphics from safe mode .

And I have seen somewhere that updating bios would fix it . Thats why I was asking for some old bios .

Comment: @TanjibRubyat - You can locate the firmware on HP's support website for your computer.  This answer even points you to the firmware package you should use.

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing  again and again . I installed latest bios from HP . But still am getting blank screen at welcome screen .